# How to get a one-to-one match of an Adorner with its adorned element within a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, adorner

wpf

I have a control A, (an inkcanvas), within a Grid within a ScrollViewer. Conrol A is taller then the physical window, so the ScrollViewer correctly adds a vertical scroll bar and the entire control can be viewed by scrolling down. When attaching an Adorner with a control B, (another inkcanvas), to control A, scrolling downward shows the Adorner to be cut off at the bottom of the screen. That is, the Adorner is not completely covering the adorned element and/or is not extended downward when scrolling.

How do I get the Adorner (the control) to completely cover the adorned element and respect the ScrollViewer. (I need a one-to-one match between the pixels of the Adorner control and the adorned element within the ScrollViewer).

TIA

Edit#1: The key line in the Adorner that sets the background of the InkCanvas is

> _inkcanvas.Background = CreateGrid();

```
public InkCanvasTextAdorner(InkCanvas element) 
            : base(element)
        {
            _element = element;

            _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
            _inkcanvas = new InkCanvas();

            _inkcanvas.Background = CreateGrid();

            _visuals.Add(_inkcanvas);   

            AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
            adornerLayer.Add(this);
        }
```

If an InkCanvas is used (as the above) the Adorner's *background* is clipped at the bottom. The adorner control, however, does continue to the bottom of the adorned element.

However, if a Canvas is used instead of the InkCanvas, the Adorner's *background*  does extend to the bottom of the adorned element.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the difference in the Background property expanding past the physical screen with the Canvas and not the InkCanvas may be because the Canvas inherits from Panel whereas the InkCanvas does not. Based on the finding that the Canvas background does do what I need, I find the below code does accomplish what I want--the canvas allows images from layers beneath it to be seen yet posts a grid of lines overwhich the InkCanvas will accept strokes.  All is well :)

```
public InkCanvasTextAdorner(InkCanvas element) 
            : base(element)
        {
            _element = element;

            // The VisualCollection has only one visual parent.  I.e. InkCanvasTextAdorner is the parent to the VisualCollection.
            // By overriding default rendering behavior of the VisualCollection, any kind of control and its children can be placed in the Adorner. 
            _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
            _inkcanvas = new InkCanvas();
            _inkcanvas.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

            _canvas = new Canvas();
            _canvas.Background = CreateGrid();

            _grid = new Grid();
            _grid.Children.Add(_canvas);
            _grid.Children.Add(_inkcanvas);

            // The _grid is a logical child of the VisualCollection of the Adorner. The ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride will set up the Grid control.
            _visuals.Add(_grid);   // Adding a single control for display.

            // AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
            AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
            adornerLayer.Add(this);
        }
```

Which looks like:
[image]